# Error using Santiment sanpy library for cryptocurrency data analysis

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, statsmodels, cryptocurrency

I am using *sanpy* to gather crypto market data, compute alpha, beta and rsquared with *statsmodels*, and then create a **crypto = input("Cryptocurrency: ")** function with a **while** loop that allows me to ask the user for an specific crypto and output its respective statistics, followed by showing the input again.

With the following code I receive the error: **ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index**

```
import san
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import statsmodels.api as sm
from statsmodels import regression

cryptos = ["bitcoin", "ethereum", "ripple", "bitcoin-cash", "tether",
"bitcoin-sv", "litecoin", "binance-coin", "eos", "chainlink",
"monero", "bitcoin-gold"]

def get_and_process_data(c):
    raw_data = san.get("daily_closing_price_usd/" + c, from_date="2014-12-31", to_date="2019-12-31", interval="1d") # "query/slug"
    return raw_data.pct_change()[1:]


df = pd.DataFrame({c: get_and_process_data(c) for c in cryptos})

df['MKT Return'] = df.mean(axis=1) # avg market return
#print(df) # show dataframe with all data

def model(x, y):
    # Calculate r-squared
    X = sm.add_constant(x) # artificially add intercept to x, as advised in the docs
    model = sm.OLS(y,X).fit()
    rsquared = model.rsquared
    
    # Fit linear regression and calculate alpha and beta
    X = sm.add_constant(x)
    model = regression.linear_model.OLS(y,X).fit()
    alpha = model.params[0]
    beta = model.params[1]

    return rsquared, alpha, beta

results = pd.DataFrame({c: model(df[df[c].notnull()]['MKT Return'], df[df[c].notnull()][c]) for c in cryptos}).transpose()
results.columns = ['rsquared', 'alpha', 'beta']
print(results)
```

The error is in the following line:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({c: get_and_process_data(c) for c in cryptos})
```

I tried solving the issue by changing it to:

```
df = {c: get_and_process_data(c) for c in cryptos}

df['MKT Return'] = df.mean(axis=1) # avg market return
print(df) # show dataframe with all data
```

But with that, it gave me a different error: **AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'mean'**.

The goal is to create a single DataFrame with the datatime column, columns for the cryptos and their *pct.change* data, an additional column for MKT Return with the daily *mean* from all cryptos' *pct.change*. Then, use all this data to calculate each crypto's statistics and finally create the input function mentioned at the beginning.

I hope I made myself clear and that someone is able to help me with this matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a great start, but I think that you are getting confused with the return from san.  If you look at

```
import san
import pandas as pd

# List of data we are interested in    
cryptos = ["bitcoin", "ethereum", "ripple", "bitcoin-cash", "tether",
"bitcoin-sv", "litecoin", "binance-coin", "eos", "chainlink",
"monero", "bitcoin-gold"]

# function to get the data from san into a dataframe and turn in into
# a daily percentage change
def get_and_process_data(c):
    raw_data = san.get("daily_closing_price_usd/" + c, from_date="2014-12-31", to_date="2019-12-31", interval="1d") # "query/slug"
    return raw_data.pct_change()[1:]

# now set up an empty dataframe to get all the data put into
df = pd.DataFrame()
# cycle through your list
for c in cryptos:
    # get the data as percentage changes
    dftemp = get_and_process_data(c)
    # then add it to the output dataframe df
    df[c] = dftemp['value']

# have a look at what you have
print(df)
```

And from that point on you know you have some good data and you can play with it as you go forward.

If I could suggest that you just get one currency and get the regressions working with that one then move forward to cycling through all of them.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing scalar values, you need to pass lists so try the following:

```
data = {c: [get_and_process_data(c)] for c in cryptos}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Maybe try this first

Comment: With that, when I _print(df)_ I obtain the following result: `                                             bitcoin  ...                                       bitcoin-gold
0                                value
datetime  ...  ...                                value
datetime  ...

[1 rows x 12 columns]`